# Spring Boot 2.6 Websocket Message Order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

we are using spring boot with websocket.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyWebsocketConnector extends TextWebSocketHandler {
   //....

   @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
      // do something...
    }
}
```

But now I found in our traces, that different messages are handled by different threads.
Therefore, I ask myself how I can guarantee that messages of a session that arrive one after the other are also processed one after the other.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything about a guaranteed order or synchronisation.

Does anyone know more about this?

The only thing I found was this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-ordered-messages

But this is the STOMP Implemantiation - we are not using STOMP  :-(

Answer (score 0):

even though I used STOMP and set the flag "setPreservePublishOrder" to true it couldn't guarantee the order. The only solution I could find that works was to set the number of threads for the client inbound channel to 1.

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(final ChannelRegistration registration) {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    executor.initialize();

    registration.taskExecutor(executor);
}
```

Comment: This hould help, but it is no solution for high frequented system :-(
Some time I think this should be an issue for guys on the spring framework?